# CURL request to soap service with standard xml envelope and pdf attachment

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, attachment

I've been desperately trying to make a call to a soap service for days with some parameters and a binary MIME attachment that will contain a PDF.

I am using an infrastructure based on Apache and PHP7.
I initially tried to use the native php soapclient class but I understand that the class does not allow to manage attachments. I then started to replicate the call tested on Soap-UI with php curl.

It seems to me that the content of the call is identical but I continue to receive a soap error.

This is the call request setup:

```
$file = "./CI_test.pdf";
$fileContents = file_get_contents($file);

$url = "https://xxxxxxxx/JProtocolloDocArea/services/DOCAREAProtoSoap";

$boundary = bin2hex ( random_bytes ( 10 ) );


$soap_request  = "";

$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "------=_Part_".$boundary;
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n";
$soap_request .= "   <soapenv:Header/>\n";
$soap_request .= "   <soapenv:Body>\n";
$soap_request .= "      <tem:inserimento>\n";
$soap_request .= "         <strUserName>ESU_PD</strUserName>\n";
$soap_request .= "         <strDST>ebFfEeBKYk9yo4jR1M1V8VdSu3VrDpLqK28OzrxiUJvYH83YY4fmAgWUgjmWF2Cb65WTPzN76w5YnKK3OlSss9bva5j29125</strDST>\n";
$soap_request .= "      </tem:inserimento>\n";
$soap_request .= "   </soapenv:Body>\n";
$soap_request .= "</soapenv:Envelope>";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "------=_Part_".$boundary;
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=CI_test.pdf";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-ID: <CI_test.pdf>";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"CI_test.pdf\"; filename=\"CI_test.pdf\"";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= $fileContents;
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
$soap_request .= "------=_Part_".$boundary."--";
$soap_request .= "\r\n";
```

This is the header setup:

```
$header = array(
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
    "Host: esupd-test.e-pal.it",
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-Type: multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<rootpart@soapui.org>\"; boundary=\"----=_Part_$boundary\"",
    "SOAPAction: \"\"",
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($soap_request)."",
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache"
);
```

And that's the CURL call:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1); // capture the header info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // turn verbose on

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What SOAP error are you receiving?

Comment: Unfortunately the error is handled with an exception that returns a personalized message to me. I'm not sure about the header configuration and the curl configuration for the request. Do you think they are configured correctly?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. Can you dump the exception message?

Comment: Thank you Matthew.. problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be considered solved.

The request failed due to a problem with the server receiving the call.

So, the PHP script that I reported can be a good way to make a call to a webservice soap that contains an xml envelope with some parameters and a binary MIME attachment.